# Why can't I put a constraint on nvarchar(max)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why can't I create a constraint on an `nvarchar(max)` column? SQL Server will not allow me to put a unique constraint on it. But, it allows me to create a unique constraint on an `nvarchar(100)` column.

Both of these columns are `NOT NULL`. Is there any reason I can't add a constraint to the `nvarchar(max)` column?

Answer (score 89):

`nvarchar(max)` is really a different data type from `nvarchar(integer-length)`. It's characteristics are more like the deprecated `text` data type.

If `nvarchar(max)` value becomes too large, like `text`, it will be stored **outside** the row (a row is constrained to 8000 bytes maximum) and a pointer to it is stored in the row itself. You cannot efficiently index such a large field and the fact that data can be stored somewhere else further complicates searching and scanning the index.
A unique constraint requires an index to be enforced and as a result, SQL Server designers decided to disallow creating a unique constraint on it.

Comment: Of course, they could have used a version of CRC or MD5 to make the constraint cheap to check with excessively high probability.  In any case; they didn't...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, you've helped explain this better than I can!

Answer (score 26):

Because MAX is really big (2<sup>31</sup>-1 bytes) and could lead to a server meltdown if the server had to check for uniqueness on multi-megabyte-sized entries.

From the documentation on [Create Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx), I would assume this holds true for unique constraints as well.

> The maximum allowable size of the
>   combined index values is 900 bytes.

**EDIT**: If you really needed uniqueness, you could, potentially approximate it by computing a hash of the data and storing that in a unique index.  Even a large hash would be small enough to fit in an indexable column.  You'd have to figure out how to handle collisions -- perhaps manually check on collisions and pad the data (changing the hash) if an errant collision is found.

Comment: To that end, is there some set maximum value that the index can be, or is it just 'not MAX'?

Comment: I think the maximum length of `nvarchar` and `varchar` is somewhere in the 8000-range, unless you use MAX.

Comment: The maximum total size of all the key columns of an index is 900 bytes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241.aspx

Comment: Since nvarchar is using two bytes to code single character, nvarchar(450) is max value that can be an index.

Answer (score 4):

A unique constraint is actually an index, and nvarchar(max) cannot be used as a key in an index.