# Simulate unique constraint using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql server 2008 and my column is nvarchar(max).
How can I simulate a unique constraint in that column using a trigger?

Is that even possible?

Comment: Why can't you create the constraint/index? Any specific reasons? It would be a better way compared to a trigger.

Comment: @Cybernate: You can't create a unique index on an nvarchar(max). See: [Why can't I put a constraint on nvarchar(max)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/why-cant-i-put-a-constraint-on-nvarcharmax)

Comment: Got it.... I was not aware of it. Thx

Comment: @Radu D: This article may be helpful. [SQL Server Unique Constraints for Large Text Columns](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1868)

Comment: I would want to seriously question why would you be asked to provide a field with unlimited length that cannot ever under any circumstances contain the same content twice. Obviously, we don't have your "business requirements", so I can't tell. But as a professional, I would push back. Whoever gave you that requirement has the onus to prove why it is needed. This is like asking for a flying car. It can be done, but you will have a lousy car that is also a lousy plane. In this case, you will have a large, unique field that is bad at both. The correct answer might very well be "don't do that".

Comment: In my view it's a perfectly reasonable requirement and nowhere near as difficult as a flying car. In a document management system for example it would make sense to ensure the same document isn't duplicated. It's an unfortunate limitation that SQL Server doesn't allow uniqueness constraints on large VARCHARs.

Comment: @dportas: In that case, you clearly would have a "sameness" indentification process for the document that is represented by a value that is shorter than the document itself. A hash would serve this purpose, and allow for far more flexibility (i.e. only sameness based on content not on header info in the file, etc, etc, etc). There is no legitimate reason to not have some sort of number as the identification (Guid, some customised format thereof, etc).

Comment: Noon: Agreed, a hash will do the job and is a workaround for the fact that SQL Server can't implement the constraint directly.

Comment: But you can't put a unique constraint on a hash... that makes no sense. It might work for you, but you're banking on good luck which is a terrible idea. Or at least, you're banking on not having bad luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the link by Joe [Why can't I put a constraint on nvarchar(max)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/why-cant-i-put-a-constraint-on-nvarcharmax) you cannot create a unique constraint.

However, you could add a `COMPUTED` column with only the first 800 (nvarchar) characters and index that uniquely.

You could reinforce that with taking a `checksum` or `hashbytes` (or both) of the nvarchar(max) column and creating a unique against (first 800 + hash)

**Don't** take the checksum or hashbytes `alone` since collisions are commonplace and you will reject even non-duplicates.

**EDIT:** For a better approach, use this method

- take the HASHBYTE of the first 8000 characters as a COMPUTED column and index it
- in the trigger, you can use the HASHBYTE of the INSERTED row's text as a quick filter to narrow down the actual records needing inspection for duplicates

```
    SELECT ..
    FROM TBL T JOIN INSERTED I ..
    WHERE HASHBYTE(I.vcmax) = T.ComputedHB
      AND I.vcmax = T.vcmax
      AND I.ID != T.ID   -- exclude self
```

Note - `ComputedHB` is the computed column

If you find any records, then there is a "unique constraint" violation

Comment: Use HashBytes to create a hash of the column and place the unique constraint on that. With SHA or MD5 you won't get accidental collisions (but if you are really paranoid use two hashes with two different algorithms!).

Comment: dportas - HashBytes only returns 128 bits. That equates to a collision rate of 1 in 2^160.  It is almost zero, but never discount that it is `not zero`.

Comment: Sure, but it's less than the risk of a Guid collision and most people don't worry much about that. It's also probably less than the risk of lightning striking your server! Don't let it keep you awake at nights.

Comment: When cost is high, even low risk may not be acceptable. I'd be embarrassed to create a system that has any chance of collision at all, statistics about unlikelihood not impressing me.

Comment: If I got it right I need to define a trigger that on insert will compute that column value and if there is already such a record in the table I will get a constraint exception and the insert will fail? Am I right? Do you know any article that show how to write such a trigger?

Answer (score 2):

Use HashBytes to create a hash of the column and place the unique constraint on that. With SHA or MD5 you won't get accidental collisions (but if you are really paranoid use two hashes with two different algorithms!).

Comment: Actually I forgot that the input size for HashBytes is limited to 8000 bytes. It's easy to get around that by creating a CLR function that wraps the .net version of the hash function which doesn't have that limitation.