# How can I enforce uniqueness on a NVARCHAR(MAX) column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column in SQL Server 2008 R2 that is NVARCHAR(MAX). I would like to set a unique index on that column, but the maximum size for a column that is included in a unique index is NVARCHAR(450) or 900 bytes.

How can I enforce uniqueness on a NVARCHAR(MAX) column?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I put a constraint on nvarchar(max)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/why-cant-i-put-a-constraint-on-nvarcharmax)

Comment: You actually can't - see above and voting to close.

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/why-cant-i-put-a-constraint-on-nvarcharmax

Comment: @Yuck - There might be a way outside the built-in constraints.  The question is about enforcing uniqueness, not necessarily adding a constraint on the field.

Comment: @JNK: Subtle..I suppose you may be right.

Comment: This may be asked elsewhere, but it is a different question than: "Why can't I put a constraint on nvarchar(max)" I think Lucero answers the asked question nicely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a persisted column on some kind of hash, such as CHECKSUM. For example: Hash = MyStringHash as CHECKSUM(MyString)
2. Create a non-unique index on that column
3. Create a trigger that enforces uniqueness. The index is needed to speed up the search in EXISTS clause:

   ```
           WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                FROM   YourTable AS y
                                WHERE  y.MyStringHash = CHECKSUM(Inserted.MyString)
                                       AND y.MyString = Inserted.MyString) ;
   ```

Important: you need to test with respect to your collation. If you are using a case-insensitive collation, make sure that the trigger will not allow both 'MyTest' and 'MYTEST'.

If you go for a unique index and stop at that, you are just creating a bug waiting to happen.

Edit: in a case-insensitive environment I have used CHECKSUM for a persisted computed column, which is fast, case-insensitive, and selective enough.

Comment: Alex, I'm assuming you mean to use CHECKSUM in a calculated column. Thanks for the solution! :)

Comment: CHECKSUM is a very poor choice: the odds of a collision are high.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same idea as Cory. Assuming that collisions with SHA1 are unlikely enough, you can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHash](
    [s] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [h]  AS (hashbytes('SHA1',[s])) PERSISTED,
    CONSTRAINT [IX_tblHash] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (
        [h]
    )
)
```

Comment: Won't work. Hashbytes is limited to 8k bytes.  You'll need to write your own hashbytes that can handle more than 8k bytes, and then deal with the fact that it's slow.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx - "Allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes."

Answer (score 2):

How do you have a field that large that you are worried about getting duplicates of?

One way would be to create a computed field like `LEFT(NvarCharMaxField, 200)` and put a unique index on **that**.  Beyond that I don't think there is a way unless you add a  trigger and that would be very expensive.

Comment: Agree, nvarchar(max) fields should not need unique indexes to start with. What is being stored inthis field and can it be refactored to a something that can be indexed?

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly use some sort of hash function against the NVARCHAR(MAX) field and create a UNIQUE INDEX on the hash field.

**EDIT:**

As Yuck pointed out, with the way hash functions work you do run the possibility of running into collisions.  If you use a hash such as SHA1 it will be (possible but) very unlikely that you will into a collision.

Comment: As with any hash function you can have collisions so this would be misleading.

Comment: @Yuck, crypto hashes such as SHA1 should be unlikely enough for collisions.

Comment: In light of what @Lucero said, edit your answer so I can remove the downvote.