# How do you create a non-clustered index for a string column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

I just tried this and got the helpful message that

Column 'Username' in table 'Users' is of a type that is 
invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Username is an nvarchar(max) column.

Comment: nvarchar(max) can't be used as a constraint / index.  Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/why-cant-i-put-a-constraint-on-nvarcharmax

Comment: Why do you want an index on an `nvarchar(max)` column? Why are you using `nvarchar(max)` for username? Do you think anyone wants a billion characters in their username? Probably `nvarchar(50), (64) or (255)` would be sufficient. `(320)` if it is going to represent an e-mail address. And I wonder if Unicode is even really a requirement here.

Comment: LOL a billion characters across multiple languages even.

Comment: The maximum size for an index entry is **900 bytes** - anything larger than that **cannot** be indexed. So you can index a `nvarchar(450)` (or a `varchar(900)`) at most - larger string columns aren't suitable for an index.

Comment: I'm glad I provided people with some amusement. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a index to a nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) column but it can be part of an index.

You can include it in an index but then that index needs to created/rebuilt offline.

Taking a guess from your column name 'Username' I would change the column type to something smaller like a nvarchar(50). The nvarchar(max) datatype can store up to 4Gb of text and is used for more full text storage (in that use you would setup full text searching).

Comment: It will also make the index huge and unmaintainable.