# What approach should i use to inform the user that the email is already being used

Tags: c#, sql-server, validation, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

Im building a .net api using razor pages and i want to validate the email input during creation so theres no email duplicates being stored into the database. I was using the UNIQUE parameter in my database design but that brought little success. This is my current User class that i scaffolded using razor pages (CRUD).

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, 
        StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, 
        ErrorMessage ="Name has to be between 2 and 20 characters long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, 
        DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), 
        RegularExpression(@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*"+ "@"+ @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$",
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Format")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    

    [Required, 
        DataType(DataType.Date), 
        Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")] 
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Additional Info"), 
        DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", 
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }

    [Required, 
        StringLength(24, MinimumLength = 8, 
        ErrorMessage = "Password has to be between 8 and 24 characters long"), 
        DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

so i tried the UNIQUE property in my SQL database like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
[ID]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]           NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
[Email]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[DateOfBirth]    DATETIME2 (7)  NOT NULL,
[AdditionalInfo] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Password]       NVARCHAR (28) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC));
```

What's best practice in a scenario like this to check if the Email is already in use ?

Comment: Query the database for the candidate email address and see if you get a record back.

Comment: `UNIQUE` works. It ensures there won't be any duplicate entries in the database. This won't automagically check the data *before* entry though. You have to do this yourself

Comment: Do we really need a RegularExpression annotation when we have already defined the DataType as an EMailAddress?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel (badly).   NEVER NEVER NEVER store passwords.  Security is hard, it's easiest if you don't write your own.  Don't use your database entity as a view model (even if 'that's the way the scaffolding works').

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thats the problem, i insert data with the exact same information and it still writes it to the database only with a different ID.

Comment: Side note, `Email` doesn't need to be of `MAX` length. according to a [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+address+maximum+length) the maximum length of an email address is 320 characters, *not* 1 billion~.

Comment: @Maginaryy again, `UNIQUE` works. The data type though, not so much. `nvarchar(max)` isn't a `size doesn't matter` type. It's meant to store documents that can be larger than 4GB in size. It *can't* be indexed. A UNIQUE constraint works by creating a unique index behind the scenes. I'm surprised `NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL UNIQUE` didn't throw an error

Comment: It does error, @PanagiotisKanavos : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8efb5db286476b007352653ef4bfe2e4). Also a `MAX` is 2GB, not 4GB.

Comment: In fact, there are questions asking [why it's impossible to add UNIQUE to nvarchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/why-cant-i-put-a-constraint-on-nvarcharmax)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im really sorry for my barbaric syntax, i just got into .net and sql so im very grateful for the feedback.

Comment: @Maginaryy this isn't a matter of barbaric syntax. The `CREATE TABLE` you posted doesn't work, so what table are you trying to use? The question contradicts itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos im using the table above to store data that i input using a create page and im trying to prevent the creation of users that use existing Emails.

Comment: @Maginaryy they are telling you that you cannot have a table like that. (and looking at the image posted, you know it) So, check your database  what is the real schema of your table and post it. Otherwise change the EMail column to _[Email] NVARCHAR (320) NOT NULL UNIQUE,_

Comment: Not only should you not store plain-text passwords, but 28 characters is also **too short**. The NIST standard says _if_ you have a maximum password length (and that's a big "if") the value should be at least 64 characters.

Comment: `[DateOfBirth]    DATETIME2` Nope - a date of birth is a **DATE**, not datetime.